# Implement "registerClass" similar to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a shopping cart object that should be able to register different product class like the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` in `UICollectionView` and cast the object dynamically.

For example:

```
@property (nonatomic) Class productClass;

_productClass *product = (_productClass*)array[0];
```

Is this allowed in objective-c? If yes, please provide some sample code, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create instances of a class you don’t know beforehand, that’s easy:

```
Class type = …;
id instance = [[type alloc] init];
```

Comment: It works perfect for init, but is it possible to cast it to an object i the array? `_productClass *product = (_productClass*)array[0];` Xcode complains about this one.

Comment: I’ve no idea what your second line is supposed to do. But Xcode is not going to like your typing, you can’t use a variable (`_productClass`) in place of a type. Try `id` instead: `id product = array[0]`.

Comment: just experimenting around the syntax :) Thanks for your solution, id is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are treated as objects in objective C so you can do almost everything you want, storing and retrieving from collections is allowed.
What I use most when I need to serialize a class name for some reason is converting it into a string and restoring it from a string.

```
[array addObject:NSStringFromClass([myObjec class])];
Class yourClass = NSClassFromString(array[0]);
```